# regex to find image sequences from list of filenames

Tags: python, regex, sequence, negative-lookbehind

I need some help with a regex string to pull any filename that looks like it might be part of a frame sequence out of a previously generated list of filenames.

Frames in a sequence will generally have a minimum padding of 3 and will be preceeded by either a `'.'` or a `'_'` An exception is: if the filename is only made up of a number and the `.jpg` extension (e.g `0001.jpg`, `0002.jpg`, etc.). I'd like to capture all these in one line of regex, if possible.

Here's what I have so far:

```
(.*?)(.|_)(\d{3,})(.*)\.jpg
```

Now I know this doesn't do the *"preceeded by `.` or `_`"* bit and instead just finds a `.` or `_` anywhere in the string to return a positive. I've tried a bit of negative lookbehind testing, but can't get the syntax to work.

A sample of data is:

```
test_canon_shot02.jpg 
test_shot01-04.jpg 
test_shot02-03.jpg 
test_shot02-02.jpg 
test_shot01-03.jpg 
test_canon_shot03.jpg 
test_shot01-02.jpg 
test_shot02.jpg
test_canon_shot02.jpg
test_shot01.jpg 
GameAssets_.00024.jpg 
GameAssets_.00023.jpg 
GameAssets_.00022.jpg 
GameAssets_.00021.jpg 
GameAssets_.00020.jpg 
GameAssets_.00019.jpg 
GameAssets_.00018.jpg 
GameAssets_.00017.jpg 
GameAssets_.00016.jpg 
GameAssets_.00015.jpg 
GameAssets_.00014.jpg 
GameAssets_.00013.jpg 
GameAssets_.00012.jpg 
GameAssets_.00011.jpg 
GameAssets_.00010.jpg 
GameAssets_.00009.jpg 
GameAssets_.00008.jpg 
GameAssets_.00007.jpg 
GameAssets_.00006.jpg 
GameAssets_.00005.jpg 
GameAssets_.00004.jpg 
GameAssets_.00003.jpg 
GameAssets_.00002.jpg 
GameAssets_.00001.jpg 
GameAssets_.00000.jpg 
OrangeXmas2015_Print_A ct2.jpg 
sh120_HF_V01-01.jpg 
sh120_HF_V01-02.jpg 
sh200_DMP_v04.jpg  
sh120_HF_V04.jpg 
sh120_HF_V03.jpg 
sh120_HF_V02.jpg 
blah_v02.jpg 
blah_v01.jpg 
blah_Capture0 4.jpg 
blah_Capture03 .jpg 
blah_Capture01. jpg 
blah_Capture02.jpg 
Wall_GraniteBlock_G rey_TC041813.jpg
Renders10_wire.jpg 
Renders10.jpg 
Renders09_wire.jpg 
Renders09.jpg 
Renders08_wire.jpg 
Renders08.jpg 
Renders07_wire.jpg 
Renders07.jpg 
Renders06_wire.jpg 
Renders06.jpg 
Renders05_wire.jpg 
Renders05.jpg 
Renders04_wire.jpg 
Renders04.jpg  
Renders03_wire.jpg 
Renders03.jpg 
Renders02_wire.jpg 
Renders02.jpg 
Renders01_wire.jpg 
Renders01.jpg 
archmodels58_057_carpinusbetulus_leaf_diffuse.jpg 
archmodels58_042_bark_bump.jpg 
archmodels58_023_leaf_diffuse.jpg 
WINDY TECHNICZNE-reflect00.jpg 
archmodels58_057_leaf_opacity.jpg 
archmodels58_057_bark_reflect.jpg 
archmodels58_057_bark_bump.jpg 
blahC-00-oknaka.jpg 
bed 
debt 
cab 
00018.jpg 
00017.jpg 
00016.jpg 
00015.jpg 
00014.jpg 
00013.jpg 
00012.jpg 
00011.jpg 
00010.jpg 
00009.jpg 
00008.jpg 
00007.jpg  
00006.jpg 
00005.jpg 
00004.jpg 
00003.jpg 
00002.jpg 
00001.jpg 
00000.jpg
```

The result I'm after is 2 sequences identified:

1. `GameAssets_.00000.jpg` to `GameAssets_.00024.jpg`
2. `00000.jpg` to `00018.jpg`

Comment: `(.|_)` is equivalent to `(.)` — perhaps you meant `[._]`?

Comment: So, why does `archmodels58_057_bark_bump.jpg` not qualify?  It has a three digit number preceded by a `_`.  Is there a rule that can be used to exclude it?

Comment: Yep, absolutely right - it should be returned too. I'd have to strip it out with another test to see if the file is actually part of a sequence.

Comment: @squeamish ossifrage : It's meant to read '.' or '_'   The [._ ] seems to return anything with both . and _ in the filename. Sorry - the formatting is broken....

Answer (score 1):

Based on the rules you specified in your question, this pattern should accomplish what you need:

```
(^|\r?\n|.*_|.*\.)\d{3,}.*\.jpg
```

Comment: The regex101.com tester shows that this regex matches these names:  archmodels58_057_carpinusbetulus_leaf_diffuse.jpg 
archmodels58_042_bark_bump.jpg 
archmodels58_023_leaf_diffuse.jpg 
archmodels58_057_leaf_opacity.jpg 
archmodels58_057_bark_reflect.jpg 
archmodels58_057_bark_bump.jpg

Comment: @DavidCullen Agreed, but according to DaveW in his comment above, that is the desired result.  If there are any additional rules that could be applied to skip those matches, he did not provide them.

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in re.findall(r'.*?[._]?0{3,}.*',data):
    print(item)

GameAssets_.00024.jpg
GameAssets_.00023.jpg
GameAssets_.00022.jpg
GameAssets_.00021.jpg
GameAssets_.00020.jpg
GameAssets_.00019.jpg
GameAssets_.00018.jpg
GameAssets_.00017.jpg
GameAssets_.00016.jpg
GameAssets_.00015.jpg
GameAssets_.00014.jpg
GameAssets_.00013.jpg
GameAssets_.00012.jpg
GameAssets_.00011.jpg
GameAssets_.00010.jpg
GameAssets_.00009.jpg
GameAssets_.00008.jpg
GameAssets_.00007.jpg
GameAssets_.00006.jpg
GameAssets_.00005.jpg
GameAssets_.00004.jpg
GameAssets_.00003.jpg
GameAssets_.00002.jpg
GameAssets_.00001.jpg
GameAssets_.00000.jpg
00018.jpg
00017.jpg
00016.jpg
00015.jpg
00014.jpg
00013.jpg
00012.jpg
00011.jpg
00010.jpg
00009.jpg
00008.jpg
00007.jpg
00006.jpg
00005.jpg
00004.jpg
00003.jpg
00002.jpg
00001.jpg
00000.jpg
```

Comment: Trying to work out exactly is going on here - why does it not return archmodels58_057_carpinusbetulus_leaf_diffuse.jpg for example?

Comment: I see - this only works if the numbers are at the end of the filename... Will look at the usecase and see if this is viable. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(.*?)(\.|_?)(000\d{0,})(.*)\.jpg
```

Notice that I had to escape the `'.'` in the second group. Also, I had to make the search for `'.'` and `'_'` optional in the second group. Finally, I had to add the minimum padding to the third group.

I used regex101.com to test and refine the regex: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uP0bJ4/1)